# There is a way to encode query params in base64 using insomnia rest client?

Tags: rest, base64, insomnia

I've been using insomnia for a while now and it has served me quite well. But when i need to make some more complex requests i don't know how to do it. Basically i need to make a GET request with a @request query param, that must hold a JSON encoded in base64. How can i do this **inside insomnia**? The template tag that does this job doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this by using the built in base64 function tag. Once I added this I was able to add a value to the tag that I wanted encoded (in my case an env var)

Comment: You have to click on the base64 function button once it gets added (press ctrl + space) then click on the function button then it pops up with a form to fill in. Works well. Was not clear it was clickable to me.